# The geometric action of an orthogonal $3 \times 3$ matrix with determinant $-1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, orthogonality

I am trying to prove that the action of an orthogonal $3\times 3$ matrix with determinant $-1$ is a reflection about an eigenvector in one of the matrix's eigenspace, but I am a little lost.

**Problem Statement:** Describe geometrically the action of an orthogonal $3×3$ matrix with determinant $-1$.

What I have so far for the proof:

> Claim that $A$ is an orthogonal $3×3$ matrix with determinant $-1$. Since $A$ is $3×3$, $A$ must have $3$ eigenvalues, $λ_1$, $λ_2$, and $λ_3$, and we know that $λ_1 λ_2 λ_3=-1$ must hold. Then we know that either
>
> Case 1: $λ_1,λ_2,λ_3=-1$
>
> Case 2: $λ_1,λ_2=1, λ_3=-1$
>
> Case 3: $λ_1=-1, λ_2=c, λ_3=\bar{c}$  where $c,\bar{c}∈C$ and $\bar{c}$ is the complex conjugate of $c$.

Now, I am unsure what to do from here. My teacher was doing a similar proof in class where he was proving that the geometric action of a $3\times 3$ matrix with determinant $1$ is a rotation about one eigenspace. And based on his proof, I was thinking that I should do the following for this proof:

> Let **$v$** be an eigenvector with eigenvalue $-1$. Then we have
> $v^{⊥}=\left\{\ w∈F^{3}   |  v⋅w=0\right\}$
> is a two dimensional vector subspace. Since $A$ is orthogonal, $Av^⊥⊂v^⊥$.

Now, based on what my teacher was telling me, he was saying the other two eigenspaces make a plane orthogonal to the eigenspace for $\lambda =-1$ and that $A$ reflects any vector about the eigenline for $\lambda = -1$?

Am I on the right track here? Any clarification for where I should go from here would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a completely geometric description that doesn't have to talk about entries of A.

You've analyzed the eigenvalues correctly. Let v be an eigenvector for -1. Let T be the reflection of three space in the plane normal to v. Then TA=R is an orthogonal transformation with determinant 1, aka a rotation. In fact, you will easily see that v is an eigenvector for +1 for TA,=R so that it is the axis of rotation of TA (unless TA is already the identity, where it follows that T=A.)

Since T is its own inverse, you have the equation A=TR. Now you can see that A is a rotation around v, then a reflection through the plane normal to v.

> $A$ reflects any vector about the eigenline for $\lambda = -1$

You mean *rotates.* In 3-space, you can rotate about a line or reflect in/through a plane, but "reflect about a line" is not sensical.

> he was saying the other two eigenspaces make a plane orthogonal to the eigenspace for $\lambda =-1$.

The wrong part of this is that *most* of the time there are no other eigenspaces. You are guaranteed at least one dimension of eigenspace, but if the other two values are nonreal complex, *there is no more eigenspace out there*. The special cases are when the rotation is by 0 radians and by $\pi$ radians, where respectively there would be a two dimensional eigenspace for 1, or two more dimensions in the -1 eigenspace.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint.

The restriction of the transformation $A$ to the orthogonal plane $v^\perp$ is itself the transformation of a $2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrix $B = \pmatrix{x & y \\ z & w}$ (with respect to an orthonormal basis $u_1,u_2$ of the 2-dimensional vector subspace $v^\perp$), such that the determinant of $B$ equals $1$. It follows that there is a $3 \times 3$ orthonormal basis change matrix $M$ such that $M v = \pmatrix{1 \\ 0 \\ 0}$, $M u_1 = \pmatrix{0 \\ 1 \\ 0}$, and $M u_2 = \pmatrix{0 \\ 1 \\ 1}$ and such that
$$M A M^{-1} = \pmatrix{-1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & x & y \\ 0 & z & w}
$$
So the $3 \times 3$ problem can be reduced to a $2 \times 2$ problem which you may already know: describe geometrically the action of an orthogonal $2 \times 2$ matrix with determinant $+1$.

Comment: So I'm still a little confused. You are saying that $Av^{⊥}$ is equivalent to $Bw$ for some $2\times 2$ matrix $B$ and $w\in F^{2}$? And so if $v=<1,0,0>$ then the only vector in $v^{⊥}$ would be the zero vector?

Comment: No, I'm talking about changing basis. I'll rewrite it more clearly.